# Oracle - BULK UPDATE with CURSOR LOOP

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulkupdate

I want to perform an update on a huge table on a table like this (I now it's not best practise):

```
TARGET_TABLE (
TICKET_ID number,
product_id number,
NET number(15,2),
VAT number(15,2));
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d39ed/3

Aim: `UPDATE TARGET_TABLE set NET=VAT, VAT=NET`

I came up with a BULK UPDATE, but I get an ORA-00913: "To many values" at line 43 which I can't explain. Also, I don't know how to update two rows at once in that variant.
Could anyone help out?

```
DECLARE

-- new data
    CURSOR new_data_cur IS
      select 
                     a.rowid, 
                     a.TICKET_ID,
                     a.product_id,
                     b.NET,
                     b.VAT
 from TARGET_TABLE a
                     join TARGET_TABLE_COPY b
                     on  ( a.TICKET_ID=b.TICKET_ID AND  a.product_id =b.product_id ) ;

    TYPE new_data_type IS TABLE OF new_data_cur%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    new_data_tab       new_data_type;
    TYPE row_id_type IS TABLE OF ROWID INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    row_id_tab         row_id_type;
    TYPE rt_update_cols IS RECORD (
        NET   TARGET_TABLE.NET%TYPE
      --  VAT   TARGET_TABLE.VAT%TYPE
    );
    TYPE update_cols_type IS
        TABLE OF rt_update_cols INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    update_cols_tab1    update_cols_type;
    --update_cols_tab2    update_cols_type;
    dml_errors EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA exception_init ( dml_errors,-24381 );

BEGIN

    OPEN new_data_cur;
    LOOP
        FETCH new_data_cur BULK COLLECT INTO new_data_tab LIMIT 50000;
        EXIT WHEN new_data_tab.count=0;
        FOR i IN new_data_tab.first..new_data_tab.last LOOP
            row_id_tab(i) := new_data_tab(i).rowid;
            update_cols_tab1(i).NET := new_data_tab(i).VAT;
           -- update_cols_tab2(i).VAT := new_data_tab(i).NET;
        END LOOP;

        FORALL i IN new_data_tab.first..new_data_tab.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS # ORA-00913: To many values
            UPDATE TARGET_TABLE
           -- SET row = update_cols_tab(i)
            SET row = update_cols_tab1(i) 
           --         row = update_cols_tab2(i) 
            WHERE ROWID = row_id_tab(i);

        COMMIT;
        EXIT WHEN new_data_tab.count=0;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
    CLOSE new_data_cur;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN dml_errors THEN

            FOR i IN 1..SQL%bulk_exceptions.count LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line('Some error occured');
            END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: Why are you doing this like this, when you could just do `UPDATE TARGET_TABLE set NET=VAT, VAT=NET;`?

Comment: >500.000.000 records

Comment: So? It's still going to be faster to update the table in a single update statement than to do the bulk update.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try renaming the columns (net -> net_vat, vat -> net, net_vat -> vat). That assumes that nothing does `select *` or an insert into target_table without specifying the column list being inserted into in your production code, though. You could potentially reorder the columns using dbms_redefinition if you absolutely needed to, though.

Comment: Alternatively you can temporarely add a column `UP2DATE INTEGER DEFAULT 0` and then do `UPDATE TARGET_TABLE set NET=VAT, VAT=NET, UP2DATE = 1 WHERE UP2DATE = 0 AND ROWNUM < 10000` to update the data chunk wise...

Comment: @Boneist It's not sure that a single update statement is faster. Often you get problems with the undo segments when you have to update huge amounts of data, so you want to do it chunk wise to avoid this kind of problems...

Comment: @Radagast81 you can run out of undo tablespace, that's true. But that doesn't impact performance, providing the undo tablespace is large enough. One single update statement across all rows will be faster than having to loop over the same table, however big the chunks are (you're now introducing context switching, not to mention repeated table/index scans!

Comment: @Boneist yes you can run out of tablespace but more often you get the ram swapping. So a low amount of context switches and index scans can be faster if you can avoid some ram swapping on the other side...

Comment: @Boneist It will never finish

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need an extra cursor where you are swapping the values

```
FOR i IN new_data_tab.first..new_data_tab.last LOOP
        row_id_tab(i) := new_data_tab(i).rowid;
        update_cols_tab1(i).NET := new_data_tab(i).VAT;
       -- update_cols_tab2(i).VAT := new_data_tab(i).NET;
    END LOOP;
```

So you code will use these values in your bulk update

```
DECLARE

-- new data
CURSOR new_data_cur IS
  select 
                 a.rowid, 
                 a.TICKET_ID,
                 a.product_id,
                 b.NET,
                 b.VAT
   from TARGET_TABLE a
                 join TARGET_TABLE_COPY b
                 on  ( a.TICKET_ID=b.TICKET_ID AND  a.product_id =b.product_id ) ;

TYPE new_data_type IS TABLE OF new_data_cur%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
new_data_tab       new_data_type;
TYPE row_id_type IS TABLE OF ROWID INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
row_id_tab         row_id_type;
TYPE rt_update_cols IS RECORD (
    NET   TARGET_TABLE.NET%TYPE
  --  VAT   TARGET_TABLE.VAT%TYPE
);
TYPE update_cols_type IS
    TABLE OF rt_update_cols INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
update_cols_tab1    update_cols_type;
--update_cols_tab2    update_cols_type;
dml_errors EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA exception_init ( dml_errors,-24381 );

BEGIN

OPEN new_data_cur;
LOOP
    FETCH new_data_cur BULK COLLECT INTO new_data_tab LIMIT 50000;
    EXIT WHEN new_data_tab.count=0;


    FORALL i IN new_data_tab.first..new_data_tab.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS # ORA-00913: To many values
        UPDATE TARGET_TABLE
       -- SET row = update_cols_tab(i)
       -- SET row = update_cols_tab1(i) 
       --         row = update_cols_tab2(i) 
        NET =  update_cols_tab1(i).VAT
        VAT = update_cols_tab1(i).NET
        WHERE ROWID = row_id_tab(i);

    COMMIT;
    EXIT WHEN new_data_tab.count=0;
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
CLOSE new_data_cur;

EXCEPTION
WHEN dml_errors THEN

        FOR i IN 1..SQL%bulk_exceptions.count LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('Some error occured');
        END LOOP;
END;
```